# Third order radical limit, issue with conjugate

Tags: limits

How do I calculate this limit? Should be equal to 1, but I just can't figure out how to prove it. I tried multiplying with the conjugate but I think I'm not doing something right...

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\left(x^3+3x^2-4\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-x\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a difference of two cubes rationalisation:
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3 + 3x^2 - 4} - x}{1} = \frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - 4 - x^3}{(\sqrt[3]{x^3 + 3x^2 - 4})^2 + x \sqrt[3]{x^3 + 3x^2 - 4} + x^2}$$
Then divide top and bottom by $x^2$, simplify, let $x \rightarrow \infty$, and you should get a limit of $1$.

Comment: I was trying that just now. I didn't know this was called two cubes rationalisation. Thank you, solved it! :-)

Comment: Well, that's what I call it!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2-4}=\\\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2+3x+1-(3x+1)-4}=\\\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3-3x-5}\\$$when $x \rightarrow \infty $we can write $$\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3-3x-5} \approx \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3} $$ then the limit is +1